# what port is this

Tags: port

I've not seen this port before, it looks kind of like a HDMI port and has this symbol next to it... what is it?

[image]

It's on the back panel of a desktop computer.

Comment: Could you run the image through a few blur filters? It's too sharp. :P

Comment: Can you post a picture of the port as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).  It's a video connector.  It can be converted to HDMI, DVI, S-video or Analog VGA if needed.

"DisplayPort is a digital display interface standard put forth by the Video Electronics Standards Association (VESA) since 2006. It defines a new royalty-free, digital audio/video interconnect, intended to be used primarily between a computer and its display monitor, or a computer and a home-theater system."

Comment: Not just any DisplayPort, but more specifically a Dual-Mode DisplayPort, which allows the conversion to HDMI or single-link DVI with an inexpensive passive adapter. Without those two + signs, there is no guarantee that such adapters will work. In such a case, conversion to HDMI or DVI would require a smarter, more expensive adapter that decodes the DisplayPort protocol into raw image data and generates the respective HDMI/DVI signals from that data.